# onActivityResult is not called after returning from Gallery or Camera

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-camera, android-gallery, android-camera-intent

I need to open Camera or Gallery to upload photo into my App and then work with it. Problem is that after calling `startActivityForResult()`, when I take a photo and click X or OK button it will return me to my app, but `onActivityResult` is not called at all. Any reason why it is not working? Because this mechanism worked like 1 year ago. I reused it from other project. The only difference is that I'm using `Fragments` in this project. I implemented override of `onActivityResult` for both `MainActivity` and `Fragment`, but none of those methods were called as I came back from Gallery/Camera.

Code:

Gallery:

```
private fun openGallery() {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
    fragment?.activity?.let{it.startActivityForResult(intent, 
    GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE)}?:kotlin.run{App.showToast("Internal Error")}
}
```

Camera:

```
private fun openCamera() {
        val tempFile = createImageFile()
        photoPath = tempFile.absolutePath
        photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(a, app.packageName + ".fileprovider", tempFile)

        val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri)
        if (intent.resolveActivity(a.packageManager) != null) {
            fragment?.activity?.let{it.startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)}?:kotlin.run{App.showToast("Internal Error")}
        }
}
```

Fragment and MainActivity:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        when(requestCode){
            CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE -> {
                maybeProcessPhoto(requestCode, resultCode, data)
            }
            GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE -> {
               maybeProcessPhoto(requestCode, resultCode, data)
            }
            else -> super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        }
}
```

UPDATE:

Problem was that I called `startActivityForResult` from `custom made class`, which is like Block managing photo editing. I just sent `Fragment` object to its constructor upon initialization and called `fragment?.startActivityForResult()` which didnt return anything to `onActivityResult`. I had to sent there function as parameter and in that function I had to call `startActivityForResult`. Which from my point of view is exactly same because both calls were on Fragment object, but it looks like you can open new activity from referenced Fragment but result will not return. You have to directly call startActivityForResult from Fragment itself to get result.

Example:

```
class CameraBlock(
        private val app: App,
        private val a: Activity,
        private val f: Fragment? = null,
        private val onIntent: (Intent, Int)->Unit
){


  private fun openGallery(){
     val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
    //DOESNT WORK
    f?.let{it.startActivityForResult(intent, 
    GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE)}?:kotlin.run{App.showToast("Internal Error")}
    
    //THIS WORKS
    onIntent.invoke(intent, GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE)
  }
}
```

Fragment:

```
override fun onCreateView(li: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, si: Bundle?): View? {
        return (li.inflate(R.layout.photo_select, container, false) as ViewGroup).apply {
            openGalleryButton = CameraBlock(
                    app = app,
                    a = parentActivity,
                    f = this@PhotoFragment,
                    onIntent = ::openIntent
            )

        }
    }
 
private fun openIntent(int: Intent, code: Int){
        startActivityForResult(int, code)
    }
```

Comment: You have to start Intent for gallery and camera from the activity directly instead of fragment. To communicate between your fragment and activity you can use an interface in the fragments implemented by the activity. This interface contains two methods, one to open camera, the other to open gallery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE)
```

In fragment :

```
@Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Tried this and still same. No result.

Comment: Added some explanation to my update. Thats weird behavior but it works

Answer (score 0):

you can running onactivityresult method without its parent reference.use this code of piece in the OnActivityResult method:

```
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```